# Link to local file not working

Tags: html

I am trying to make a website, and have a link to my other page in the same folder as the website.html file. I typed the name of the file correct, so I can't see what the problem is. I haven't used HTML in a while.
Here is the HTML code for the link
When I click the link it says file not found.

```
<h3><a href="file:interphase.html">Interphase</a>
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Its working now! Thanks for all the help people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<h3><a href="interphase.html">Interphase</a></h3>
```

You don't need to use "file:" in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `file:`.
If your `interphase.html` file is in the same directory as the current file, it should look like this:

```
<h3><a href="interphase.html">Interphase</a></h3>
```